# How to find HtmlForm element?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to find HtmlForm element using code below and add several new controls. Unfortunately this is not working, the HtmlForm element is never found.

```
  foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {

                if (c is HtmlForm)
                {

                    c.Controls.AddAt(0, manager);
                    c.Controls.AddAt(1, updatePanel);

                }

            }
```

Comment: Are you sure there is HtmlForm defined on the page? Paste the aspx code please. Additionally, you could use `foreach (HtmlForm с in Controls.OfType<HtmlForm>())`

Comment: There is always Form element in ASP.NET app, right?

Answer (score 1):

How about using Page.Form to get the HtmlForm?

Comment: var form = Page.Form; return null in OnPreInit

Comment: To humor me, can you try adding base.OnPreInit(e); before calling Page.Form? Let me know if there's any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `runat="server"` specified in the form control?  Otherwise; your code behind won't be aware of it.

Also, you might need some recursion here if the Control has nested controls; so something like this:

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control containerCtl, string controlIdToFind)
        {
            var foundCtl = containerCtl.FindControl(controlIdToFind);
            if (foundCtl != null && controlIdToFind == foundCtl.ID)
            {
                return foundCtl;
            }

            foreach (Control ctl in containerCtl.Controls)
            {
                foundCtl = FindControlRecursive(ctl, controlIdToFind);
                if (foundCtl != null && controlIdToFind == foundCtl.ID)
                {
                    return foundCtl;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, I want to find ASP.NET default Form.

Comment: FindControlRecursive(HtmlForm, "aspnetForm");
I get error "Error System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
Could you show me an example how to pass HtmlForm element?

Comment: I might be missing the point here, but if you have something like this on your aspx page:  `<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">`, why can't you just reference `Form1` in your codebehind, instead of trying to hunt it down through the controls collection?

Comment: What Jim B said--just ID the form and referene Form1. He wanted to get a reference on the "default form" anyway.

Comment: @Jim B I can't get reference to form, I get error "Cannot resolve symbol mainform". "mainform" is my main form name which located in MasterPage.

Comment: So why not Page.Master.FindControl("mainform")?

Comment: And you'd probably help out the rest of us if you posted more of your code so we can see the real issue.